# C program on part of algorithm which focus on finding Armstrong-like number

Tags: c

I have a problem with C program. The idea of it is similar to Armstrong number checking. Say if the input number is 123. Program needs to check if condition, for example 123=1^1+2^2+3^3 is true. I know how to add digits,but have a problem with powers. It is obvious that I need a loop for powers from 1 to the number of digits. In Armstrong number algorithm you have similar power on every digit. For example 153=1^3+5^3+3^3. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,d,s=0,o,i,k;
    printf("n=");scanf("%d",&n);
    d=n;
    while(d!=0)
    {
        o=d%10;
        s=s+o;
        d=d/10;
        k++
    }

    printf("sum:%d",s);
    printf("number of digits:%d",k);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: `k` isn't initialized in your program.

Comment: So, you want to check if a 3 digit number =1^1+2^2+3^3 , a two digit number =1^1+2^2 and so on?

Comment: and k++ is missing a `;`

Comment: Hi. I need to check 153=1^1+5^2+3^3. Sorry for k. k is a number of digits and should be initialized to zero.

Comment: `sum += power(o, ++k);`... `if(sum==n)puts("yes");`

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use the debugger (`gdb`). Read documentation of every function (like [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)). Test result of `scanf`

Comment: How about my answer, why not accept it ? @NemanjaGrubor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first get the lenth of number, which is used to determine how many times you need to get into loop to calculate each bit.

For example, number 123, you first need to know the number is 3 bits len, then you can mutilply number 3 three times, number 2 twice, and number 1 once.

I use a temporary string to achieve this

here is code， a little bit alteration on yours

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NUM_LEN     16  

int main()
{
    char tmp_num[MAX_NUM_LEN] = {0};
    int len,n,d,s=0,o,i,tmp_len, tmp_o;
    printf("n=");scanf("%d",&n);
    sprintf(tmp_num, "%d", n);
    len = strlen(tmp_num);
    tmp_len = len;
    d=n;
    while(d!=0)
    {
        o=d%10;
        for (tmp_o = 1, i = tmp_len; i > 0; i--)
            tmp_o *= o;
        s=s+tmp_o;
        d=d/10;
        tmp_len--;
    }

    printf("sum:%d\n",s);
    printf("number of digits:%d\n",len);
    return 0;
}
```

results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea but it is not what program should do.

Comment: You have the same powers on every digit which is not the idea, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According of what I've understood I think this is what the OP is looking for:

```
int power(int base, int exp)
{
    if (base == 0) return 0;
    int result=1;
    while (exp-- > 0) result*=base;
    return result;
}

void calculate(int number)
{
    int d=number;
    int tmpnumber=number;
    int n=0;
    while (d > 0) 
    {
        n++;
        d /=10;
    }
    printf("Number of digits: %d\n", n);

    int k=0;
    int sum=0;
    while (n--) 
    {
        // get digits from left to right
        d=number / power(10, n);
        k++;
        sum+=power(d, k);
        number %= power(10, n);
        printf("%d^%d=%d\n", d, k, power(d, k));
    }
    printf("\n%5d %5d", tmpnumber, sum);
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int value;

    while (TRUE)
    {
        printf("Enter value (0 = Quit): "); 
        scanf("%d", &value);
        if (value <= 0) return 0;
        calculate(value);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```